# Inline import by ES6 modules in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, module, babeljs

In an "old way" of managing modules in Node.JS (CommonJS modules) you can do something like this:

Example of Express.js route: `app.use('/user', require("./user"));`

How to do this when I am using ES6 Modules (import, export) and transcribing by Node.JS server by babel?

I can't just do: `app.use('/user', import {user} from './user');`

Comment: Do the import as a separate statement and then `app.use("/user", user);`

Comment: Sure it is option but then its loosing point of my question becase same way I can require module into variable and then do `app.use('/user', user);`

Comment: Well `import` and `export` have to be done at the outer lexical level, so you really cannot do what you're asking.

Comment: What import("./user") do?

Comment: An `import` that does not assign imported symbols just runs the imported script. The syntax for that would be `import "./user";`, no parentheses, and it still has to be done at the outermost lexical level.

Comment: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import

Comment: @Baterka That is a) a proposal only, not standard syntax b) returns a promise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try separating it out into multiple expressions - `import` (as well as `export`) are not available at the same lexical level as you are trying to use it the example:

```
import { user } from './user'

...

app.use('/user', user)
```

Comment: If its reallz not possible to do it like in old modules I consider this as right answer

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to do dynamic inline imports in node, detailed here:
https://javascript.info/modules-dynamic-imports

This code has worked for me:

```
let {default: foo} = await import('./foo.js');
```

Here is a working example of a function I wrote as part of a db migration tool in node.

```
const getMigrations = async (path) => {
  const migrateDir = await fs.readdirSync(path);
  const migrations = await Promise.all(migrateDir.map(async (filename) => {
    let {default: migration} = await import(`${path}/${filename}`);
    return migration;
  }));
  migrations.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.seq - b.seq;
  });
  return migrations;
};
```

Where an example migration is like:

```
export default {
  seq: 1.1,
  label: 'create user table',
  sql: `
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user;
    CREATE TABLE user
    (
      ...
    );
  `
};
```

I am using node v12.18.4 with "type": "module" in my package.json.  When I run the script, I get a warning that the ESM module loader is experimental, but it works.  However, there is a note on the page linked to above that says:

> Dynamic imports work in regular scripts, they don’t require script type="module".

I hope this helps.  I believe you should be able to apply this to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want using the following syntax:

```js
app.use('/user', (await import('./user')).user)
```